# File downloader written in ruby

Tags: ruby, api

Which APIs are necessary to make a file downloader in ruby programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace Net::HTTP contains every usefull tools for HTTP requests in ruby.

The documentation isn't very clear but it's very useful :
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html

I found this example on google :
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2469

Net::HTTP always done the job for me, i hope it's will be the same for you.